# how to make all the logcat messages levels appear

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

the proble i have is, when i run my code on Samsung-galxy the App works fine and all the logcat message levels (v,d,i,e,w) are showing. while when i run the same App on Huawei-MediaPad the App works but the Logcat messages of
level d and v do not show up.

to solve this problem i did the follwoing:

1- unplugged the device and re-plugged it again

2-pressed alt+6 twice

3-close Android studio and reopened it again

4- retarted the device

but non of the abovr attempts solved the problem.

please let me know how to make all the logcat messages levels appear

Comment: try to restart the device .. it worked for me atleast

Comment: @Tahir idid that as well...did not help

Comment: that is a Huawei device problem, I so far didn't find a way to solve it.

Comment: @VladMatvienko thanks for the good news :)

Comment: Just to confirm, has the device itself been configured to log at the required level for the appropriate tags using `adb shell setprop log.tag.<your tag here> VERBOSE`? I've encountered devices which don't log `v` or `d` unless it's specifically enabled in this way. At the same time, as Vlad said, there are also some devices which seem to stubbornly refuse to return the logs even after this has been done ...

Comment: @clownba0t any idea how to configure the device to allow the .d and .v logs?

Comment: You can try using `adb` - I wrote the specific command in my previous comment. Replace `<your tag here>` with the tag that you use for the logs you want to view.

Comment: @clownba0t actually, when i first got this device it was logging all the messages levels normally..but unexpectedly it stopped showing the .d and .v!!??

Comment: another option is using adb commands in terminal/doss